# How do I convert uint8_t (Uint8 in SDL) to a string?

Tags: c++, c, types, casting, sdl

(I have just answered this question after searching for a while, so I am asking and answering this question here for it to be here when it's needed. There are similar, but not quite the same, questions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast it to `int`. This can be consumed by a `stringstream` or otherwise converted for `string` use.

Where `colour` was a `struct SDL_Color` containing `Uint8` (a defined alias for `uint8_t`) members, the solution was

```
stringstream ss << "[colour=" << (int)colour.r << ", " << (int)colour.g << ", " << (int)colour.b << "; light=" << light << "]";
```

Comment: Avoid c style casts. STL string stream operator will cast for you. Having a typdef alias for a typedef alias seems unnecessary.

Comment: (a) Do you really think I did not try to use the value as-is in stringstream? It doesn't work for me under GCC 4.6 (b) That is not my choice, it is part of SDL.

Comment: ss << static_cast<int>(color.r);